# Show that E_n - λN is invertible for every λ∈K and determine (E_n - λN)^-1

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, inverse

Could you guys help me with this task? Let K be a field and N ∈ Mat (n×n, K) with N^k+1 = 0 for a k∈N. Show that E_n - λN is invertible for every λ∈K and determine (E_n - λN)^-1. What does this mean for the eigenvalues of N?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $E_n$? What are you confused about?

Comment: @JalexStark $E_n$ is the identity matrix of size $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is $$(E_n - \lambda N)(E_n + \lambda N + \dots + \lambda^k N^k) = E_n- \lambda^{k+1} N^{k+1} = E_n,$$
meaning that $E_n - \lambda N$ is invertible and its inverse is $E_n + \lambda N + \dots + \lambda^k N^k$.

(If you want, I can explain this answer in German as well.)

Comment: Vielen Dank. Es würde mir einfacher fallen, wenn die Erklärung in deutsch wäre!

Comment: Okay, das kriegen wir hin! Verstehst du denn schon die obige Gleichung?

Comment: Es ist $$E_n (E_n + \lambda N + \lambda^2 N^2 + \dots + \lambda^k N^k) = E_n + \lambda N + \lambda^2 N^2 + \dots + \lambda^k N^k$$ und $$-\lambda N (E_n + \lambda N + \lambda^2 N^2 + \dots + \lambda^k N^k) = -\lambda N - \lambda^2 N^2 - \lambda^3 N^3 - \dots - \lambda^{k+1} N^{k+1}.$$ Also erhalten wir mit Ausklammern $$(E_n - \lambda N)(E_n + \lambda N + \dots + \lambda^k N^k) = E_n - \lambda^{k+1} N^{k+1},$$ weil sich die Terme der Form $\lambda^k N^k$ für $k=1,\dots,k$ kürzen. Nun ist aber $N^{k+1}=0$ nach Voraussetzung. So erhalten wir die obige Gleichung.

Comment: Ich habe meine Lösung soeben korrigiert. Mir ist beim Schreiben ein Fehler passiert, sorry! 

Weißt du nun, warum die Matrix $E_n - \lambda N$ invertierbar ist und siehst du, wie ihre Inverse aussieht?

Comment: Danke für die Mühe. Leider sehe ich nicht warum es invertierbar ist. Ich bin leider nicht sehr gut in Lineare Algebra.

Comment: Kein Problem, nur die Ruhe! Eine Matrix $A \in \operatorname{Mat}(n \times n, \mathbb{K})$ ist genau dann invertierbar, wenn es eine Matrix $A^{-1} \in \operatorname{Mat}(n \times n, \mathbb{K})$ gibt, sodass $A A^{-1} = E_n$ ist. Wenn wir $A = E_n - \lambda N$ setzen, was ist dann $A^{-1}$?

Comment: A^-1 = E_n / E_n - λN  . Stimmt das so?

Comment: Das stimmt leider nicht ganz. Man kann Matrizen im Allgemeinen nicht dividieren. Das $^{-1}$ in $A^{-1}$ bedeutet nicht, dass man den Kehrwert nimmt, wie man es z.B. in $ \mathbb{Q}$ oder $\mathbb{R}$ macht.

Die Matrix $A^{-1}$ ist eine Matrix mit der Eigenschaft $A A^{-1} = E_n$. Bedenke, dass es nicht für jede Matrix $A$ ein Inverses $A^{-1}$ gibt. Für den Fall, dass $A = E_n - \lambda N$ ist, wollen wir aber zeigen, dass es so ein $A^{-1}$ gibt. Das bedeutet nämlich, dass $E_n - \lambda N$ invertierbar ist.

Comment: Wir haben vorhin gesehen, dass $(E_n - \lambda N)(E_n + \lambda N + \lambda^2 N^2 + \dots + \lambda^k N^k) = E_n$. Wenn wir also $A = E_n - \lambda N$ setzen, dann bedeutet das also $A^{-1} = (E_n - \lambda N)^{-1} = E_n + \lambda N + \lambda^2 N^2 + \dots + \lambda^k N^k$.

Weil wir nun $(E_n - \lambda N)^{-1}$ gefunden haben, bedeutet das, dass $E_n - \lambda N$ invertierbar ist. Hast du meine Erklärung verstanden?

Comment: Ach Gott. Ich hab das komplett übersehen. Ja natürlich. Jetzt verstehe ich es. Da in der Aufgabe definiert wurde, dass N^{k+1}=0 ist fällt ja der Teil davor weg und dann kommt (E_n - \lambda N)(E_n + \lambda N + \dots + \lambda^k N^k) = E_n raus. Und da die Voraussetzung der Inverse A A^{-1} = E_n ist muss A^{-1} = (E_n + \lambda N + \dots + \lambda^k N^k) sein. Vielen Dank für die ausführliche Erklärung und dass Sie sich soviel Zeit für mich genommen haben.

Comment: Ich hätte noch eine Frage und zwar: Wie bist du auf die ersten 2 Gleichungen gekommen?

Comment: Danke, dass du meine Antwort ausgezeichnet hast :) Du meinst die zwei Gleichungen in den Kommentaren? Also ich wollte damit erklären, wie man $(E_n - \lambda N)(E_n + \lambda N + \dots + \lambda^k N^k)$ ausrechnet.
Es ist $$(E_n - \lambda N)(E_n + \lambda N + \dots + \lambda^k N^k) = E_n (E_n + \lambda N + \dots + \lambda^k N^k) - \lambda N (E_n + \lambda N + \dots + \lambda^k N^k),$$
ich habe also nur ausgeklammert.
Die erste Gleichung ist sehr leicht, weil Multiplikation mit $E_n$ nichts verändert.
Die zweite Gleichung war dann wieder reines Ausklammern. Hast du das verstanden?

Comment: Ach stimmt. Einfache Umformungen hast du gemacht und wie du gesagt hast verändert die Einheitsmatrix nichts. Aber wie kommt man zum Ausdruck in der zweiten Klammer (En+λN+⋯+λkNk)? Du bist ja davon ausgegangen. Ich sehe nicht wie man auf den Ausdruck durch die Aufgaben Beschreibung kommt. Es tut mir sehr Leid, dass ich die so lange belästige und dich höchstwahrscheinlich mit dummen Fragen löchere...

Comment: Ach, das ist kein Problem. Auf die zweite Summe kommt man hauptsächlich durch viel Erfahrung. Sie ähnelt der geometrischen Summenformel nämlich sehr, die findest du [in diesem Artikel](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Mathe_f%C3%BCr_Nicht-Freaks:_Geometrische_Summenformel). Diese Formel ist sehr bekannt und wird sehr häufig in der Mathematik benutzt.
Lass dich nicht von der linearen Algebra entmutigen. Du kannst stolz auf dich sein, weil du diese schwere Aufgabe verstanden hast.

Comment: Vielen Dank! Jetzt habe ich es komplett verstanden, dank dir. Ich versuche mein bestes. Ich versuche einfach nur Lineare Algebra 2 zu bestehen.

Answer (score 2):

1. A nilpotent matrix has only one eigenvalue: $0$.
2. For $ \lambda=0$ we have $E_n - λN=E_n$, hence $E_n - λN$ is invertible.
3. Let $ \lambda \ne 0$. Then $E_n - λN$ is invertible $ \iff N- \frac{1}{\lambda}E_n$ is invertible $ \iff \frac{1}{\lambda}$ is not an eigenvalue of $N$. Now look at 1.

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the product
$$
(E_n - \lambda N)(E_n + \lambda N + \lambda^2 N^2 + \cdots + \lambda^k N^k)
$$
Note that if $(E_n - \lambda N)$ is invertible and $\lambda \neq 0$, then $(\lambda^{-1} E_n - N)$ is invertible.  This implies that $\lambda^{-1}$ is not an eigenvalue of $N$.